# Square of the diagonal elements in a matrix

Tags: javascript

for a matrix [1,2,3,
4,5,6,
7,8,9] How to find the square of the diagonal elements for 1,5,9 and the output should throw 1 ,25,81 using javascript or python I have tried using nested loops concept but I either keep on getting the product of the sum of the diagonal elemnts

Comment: What code are you using and what errors are you getting?

Comment: A "matrix" typically looks like `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` rather than a single array like `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] for tips on how to ask a question less likely to receive downvotes and close votes.

Comment: @HereticMonkey depends, WebGL usually uses one-dimensional array

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your code that is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is your Matrix `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`

```js
const matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];

const answer = [];

matrix.map((row, index) => {
    answer.push(row[index] * row[index]);
})

console.log(answer)
```

How does it work?
very easy, the row number and index of the diagonal element is same